# JavaScript classList is not working. I've tried various methods I've seen on here

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and for some reason I cannot for the life of me get a simple button to add a class to my links. I've tried a few different approaches that I've seen on here, and I get nothing. I'm embarrassed to say I've been at this for about 2 hours. I don't want to use jQuery because I want to learn JS, so if you could please provide the answer in raw JavaScript and explain your answer I would appreciate it. Thank you.

html:

```
<div class='col-9 text-right'>
    <ul class='navlinks'>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>

    </ul>
    <p class='cheesebrgr'>click</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var fries = function () {
       var milkshake = document.getElementsByTagName(' li ');
        for (i = 0; i < milkshake.length; i++); {
            milkshake[i].classList.add('op1');
        }   
    };
    var napkin = document.getElementsByClassName('cheesebrgr');
    napkin.addEventListener('click', fries);
```

**just read two more similar questions with no luck.

Comment: Can you share the html and also where thiss class `cheesebrgr` is used?

Comment: _I don't want to use jQuery_ then never add [tag:jQuery] to your question

Comment: @Satpal I figured if someone knew jQuery, then perhaps they may have taken the time to learn JS so they would have a better understanding of what they were doing. No need to be rude.

Comment: @brk I've added it.

Comment: @EricaKnight, I am not rude, when you tag a question with specific tag, then it gives message that solution will be acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of problems in your code

1. `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a list so you have to iterate to attach event listener
2. You are misplace `;` in and terminated `for` loop

*Code*

```
for (i = 0; i < milkshake.length; i++); //<//misplace semi-colon end of for loop
```

```js
var fries = function() {
  var milkshake = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < milkshake.length; i++) {
    milkshake[i].classList.add('op1');
  }
};
var napkin = document.getElementsByClassName('cheesebrgr');
napkin[0].addEventListener('click', fries);

//If you single element with cheesebrgr class
//var napkin2 = document.querySelector('.cheesebrgr');
//napkin2.addEventListener('click', fries);
```

```css
.op1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-9 text-right'>
    <ul class='navlinks'>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>

    </ul>
    <p class='cheesebrgr'>click</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.